# symfony2 login based on manual

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am trying to implement a login in symfony2 based on their security example from manual, but something seems to be wrong, it doesn't show any errors, or any message whatsoever. This is the controller:

```
  <?php

namespace WN\Bundle\UsersBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use WN\Bundle\UsersBundle\Entity\User;
use WN\Bundle\UsersBundle\Entity\UsersRepository;

class SecurityController extends Controller {

    public function loginAction() {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR))
        {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

        }
        else
        {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }
        return $this->render('WNUsersBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
                array('last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                        'error' => $error
                        ));
    }

}

?>
```

Update:

This is the bundle/config/routing.yml

```
wn_home:
    pattern:  /secured
    defaults: { _controller: WNHomeBundle:Home:index }
wn_users_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: WNUsersBundle:Default:index }
wn_users_register:
    pattern:  /register
    defaults: { _controller: WNUsersBundle:Register:register }
wn_users_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: WNUsersBundle:Security:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check
```

This is the security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        WN\Bundle\UsersBundle\Entity\User: sha256
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
         users:
            entity: { class: WNUsersBundle:User }   

    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/secured
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
         - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

And this is the login.html.twig

```
  {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">

    <label for="Username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="_username" id="username" value="{{ last_username }}">

    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="_password" id="password">
    <br />

    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Right now the error that i get is:
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: This is not really clear. What are you trying to do, what are you expecting to get? How is it different than what you get?

Comment: i am trying to test login.i have a login form in which i put username and password.for example,i leave the fields empty,and i submit it.in the view i have {% if error %}
<div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

Comment: $request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR) - is false and $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR) is null

Comment: Can you post the view code?

Comment: {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{{ path('wn_users_login') }}" method="post">

<label for="Username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">

<label for="Password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<br />

<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>

{% endblock %}.sorry i'm new to stackoverflow not sure how to format the code in comment.

Comment: I should have mentioned edit your post instead of putting code in the comments :) Anyway, how is `'wn_users_login` routed (where does it go)?

Comment: wn_users_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: WNUsersBundle:Security:login }

Comment: Ok because that's where you should use `{{ path('login_check') }}` insead. Can you give it a try?

Comment: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "login_check" as such route does not exist.") in WNUsersBundle:Security:login.html.twig at line 6.".I have firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            security: false

Comment: Please check that your config matches the relevant parts here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form (pay special attention to the `login_check` parts)

Answer (score 0):

You must have two other public functions defined in your login controller.  You don't put anything in them, they are just stumps for the Symfony2 security controller mechanism to work.

```
/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
}
```

Hope this helps you out.